# Use OpenCV in existing Java Android application

Tags: android, python, opencv

I need to have some code to do some image processing in an existing Android app written in java. Currently my code is written in Python with OpenCV, and running on a PC. 
Now I need it too run in the said app too.

I tried running it via sl4a with py4a, which for simple python scripts is OK, but I need to use OpenCV, and couldn't figure how to format it for py4a. (Any idea how to do this?)

What are my options for running Python code using OpenCV inside of an existing Java Android app?

Comment: you'll have to port & install cv2.pyd (and all its dependancies) to android. good luck with that!

Comment: honestly, c++ / java are your only options atm. when using opencv on android

Comment: Yeah, kinda guessed that was going to be the only answer.. Still, can't blame me for hoping.. Thanks Berak.